# Apex - Create workspace user automatically when creating the user in the access control form

Tags: access-control, oracle-apex-5.1

Hi I need to setup a new user in Apex you must first create them as a workspace user, then again as an app user in the access control for of that app.
I want to create a user in the form and have the apex user created in the background via PLSQL.
I found example code once that did it and it was great, can't find it now, anyone know how to do this?
I am sure I am not the first person to not want to set it up twice for each user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I may have found it, will test then confirm.

```
APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER(
    p_user_id                      NUMBER                  IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_user_name                    VARCHAR2                IN
    p_first_name                   VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_last_name                    VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_description                  VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_email_address                VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_web_password                 VARCHAR2                IN
    p_web_password_format          VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_group_ids                    VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_01                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_02                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_03                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_04                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_05                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_06                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_07                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_08                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_09                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL
    p_attribute_10                 VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT NULL)
```

Credit to [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b32258/api.htm#BABCFBGG)